# How to restrict occurrence of a character in regex?

Tags: java, regex

I want to check if a string consists of letters and digits only, and allow a `-` separator:

`^[\w\d-]*$`

Valid: `TEST-TEST123`

Now I want to check that the separator occurs only once at a time. Thus the following examples should be invalid:

Invalid: `TEST--TEST`, `TEST------TEST`, `TEST-TEST--TEST`.

Question: how can I restrict the repeated occurrence of the a character?

Comment: Use `^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$`

Comment: `^[^\W_]+(?:-[^\W_]+)*$`

Comment: btw `\d` is not needed when you have `\w` so `^\w+(?:-\w+)*$` would be fine

Answer (score 3):

You may use

```
^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)?$
```

Or, in Java, you may use an alphanumeric `\p{Alnum}` character class to denote letters and digits:

```
^(?:\p{Alnum}+(?:-\p{Alnum}+)*)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YqwaLs/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of the string
- `(?:` - start of an optional non-capturing group (it will ensure the pattern matches an empty string, if you do not need it, remove this group!)

  - `\p{Alnum}+` - 1 or more letters or digits
  - `(?:-\p{Alnum}+)*` - zero or more repetitions of

    - `-` - a hyphen
    - `\p{Alnum}+` - 1 or more letters or digits
- `)?` - end of the optional non-capturing group
- `$` - end of string.

In code, you do not need the `^` and `$` anchors if you use the pattern in the `matches` method since it anchors the match by default:

```
Boolean valid = s.matches("(?:\\p{Alnum}+(?:-\\p{Alnum}+)*)?");
```